# Sending input names in Django form having javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have the following code:

```
<form id="buttonForm" action = "/goSomeWhere" method="post" >
    <input type="submit" name="bnext" value="Next Page" >
    <input type="submit" name="bprevious" value="Previous Page" >
</form>
```

When either one of this two buttons are submitted I receive "bnext" or "bprevious" values in Django View request.POST so I can further construct the logic that I need.

But when I'm trying to insert some javascript for the second button I loose those values:

```
<input type="submit" name="bnext" value="Next Page" >
<input type="submit" name="bprevious" id="bpid" onclick="disable()" value="Previous Page" >

function disable()
{
     document.getElementById("bpid").disabled = true;
     document.getElementById("buttonForm").submit();
}
```

There is a way to do this and still receiving input names values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sorry I didn't fully understood that what you are trying to do*

If you are trying to stop form submission then:

```
function disable() {

   document.getElementById("bpid").disabled = true;

   document.getElementById("buttonForm").preventDefault();
 }
```

If you want that client should not click previous button again then, it is best to change inputType `submit` to `hidden`:

```
function disable() {
    document.getElementById("bpid").type="hidden";
    document.getElementById("buttonForm").submit();
 }
```

**Or**

create new `<input type=hidden>`, set name values ,append to form and submit it:

```
function disable() {
   document.getElementById("bpid"). disabled=true;
   newip= document.createElement("input");
   newip.type="hidden";
   newip.name="bprevious";
   newip.value="Previous Page";

document.getElementById("buttonForm").appendChild(newip);


document.getElementById("buttonForm").submit();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Rk003. This was exactly what I was looking for:                              
`function disable() {
    document.getElementById("bpid").type="hidden";
    document.getElementById("buttonForm").submit();
 }`

Answer (score 0):

try to use button instead input like this

```
<button name="bprevious" id='bpid' onclick='disable()' value="Previous Page">Previous Page</button>
```

Comment: Same thing happens when I'm using button tag: I'm not receiving any values in the request.POST as I do without the javascript.

Comment: have you set the value in the button tag?

Comment: Did but still ...the same.